# How to make PHP set HTTP status code to 500 automatically in case of any error condition? (including those that cannot be handled by user)

Tags: php, apache, http, xdebug

I am running Apache 2.2.15 with PHP 5.3.2, 'display_errors' disabled, 'display_startup_errors' disabled, 'log_errors' enabled.

At my setup (so I consider it a norm), PHP aborts on fatal errors, which is good, and *sets HTTP status code to 500*. Fatal errors include E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_USER_ERROR and, probably, E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR (cannot trigger it myself, so can't easily check what happens). I think it is a good idea that it does set the code to 500, because I think it is the right thing to do - obviously if your script contains syntax errors and/or fails to do what is supposed to do at runtime, it is a server error, if we consider PHP part of the server.

**Now, here is the important part:**

Anyway, I have now installed XDebug to track errors better, but I can see that now, no matter the error, even though the script aborts as before on fatal errors, *the HTTP status code is always 200*. This breaks my client that 'talks' to Apache/PHP via HTTP :|

Also, setting display_errors to On/1, makes PHP no longer set HTTP status code to 500 and exhibits exactly the same behavior as with XDebug above.

I am very much dependent on reliable status code behavior here, and this all leads me to believe it's some kind of fluke or random like weather.. or am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

There is a blog post which oulines the issue:
http://talideon.com/weblog/2008/02/php-errors.cfm

For my part, I have disabled XDebug, seeing as it is what causes the bad behavior in the first place. I only used it for stack tracing anyway, and now use a custom error handler for that instead. Also, the linked article is from 2008, apparently PHP **does** set HTTP status code to 500 automatically these days. It does so here. Without XDebug, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using a custom error handler to emit the 500.

I don't know XDebug that well, but according to [this article](http://devzone.zend.com/article/2803), it registers its own error handler, probably overriding yours in the process:

> Please note that the extended error display of xdebug does not work if you define a custom error handler using register_error_handler(). This is because xdebug internally uses the same mechanism. Should your scripts use a custom error handler, you can still use the function xdebug_get_function_stack() to output the stack trace in your custom error handler.

However, for production use, you are not going to activate XDebug anyway, are you?

As for why a 200 is output when you activate `display_errors()`, that I don't understand. Can you post your custom error handler function to look at?

Comment: Nonono, I don't emit anything! I want PHP to set the code to 500 whenever an error occurs, regardless whether I myself triggered it or something went wrong with parsing or running the script.

Even though for production I won't activate it, I can't work with my scripts when XDebug is enabled because the status codes are broken, which means I can either test using "release" profile or debug without XDebug.

I don't have any custom error handler, why do you think I have one? :-)

Comment: Pekka, I found someone expressing himself much better than me on exactly the same issue I have: http://talideon.com/weblog/2008/02/php-errors.cfm
I wonder if this has been solved since. I mean, is the guy totally on point here or what!

Comment: @amn interesting and surely a good point! But how are you *currently* making PHP emit the 500 error? Is there an INI setting?

Comment: No, that's the thing - apparently since the linked post, PHP devs have come to their senses, because my PHP (5.3.2) **does** set HTTP code to 500 on errors. But once I enable XDebug, it's back to 200 OK no matter what. I have now disabled XDebug, and use a custom error handler that prints the stack (all I needed in XDebug anyway). Maybe I'll edit the original question to reflect the changes.

Comment: @amn yeah, do edit it, that PHP emits a 500 automatically is news to me, interesting to know!

Comment: Pekka, would you be so kind as to try it yourself? Just to confirm my PHP is not going weirding ways? I swear, I saw it once give me a 200 OK on a fatal error (no error handler, display {startup} errors=off). I am becoming religious here, as my client depends on proper status codes.

Comment: @amn I have only 5.3.1 at my disposal right now (Apache 2.2, Windows 7). I consistently get 200 s no matter what I do - parse errors, syntax errors, user errors etc. Display_errors is on.

Comment: However, I can't find any mention of this in the 5.3.2 changelog: http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php odd. Are you sure there is no other extension installed that could cause this?

Comment: Update: I have seen it said that when display_errors is turned to 0, throwing a 500 is indeed PHP's default action. But I can't find this documented anywhere on the PHP site.

Comment: I asked a question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075355/php-emitting-500-on-errors-doc-links

Comment: Pekka, like I said, you will get 200 OK when display_errors is on. I do too. It seems that PHP considers errors no longer errors if these are sent to output :-) But I see you are up to the fact, but just in case..

Comment: @amn Cheers, I understand now. Gordon's link in the other question pretty much explains it I think. I guess XDebug is interfering in some way so PHP thinks it's not an empty page any more, even if it is. I think this can be sorted reliably only through a custom error handler that does the `header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");` for you - even though it may be worth filing your findings as a bug. The question is just where: PHP or XDebug? It would have to be both at first...