# Error at php script didn`t handle by $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, timeout

**I have these code:**

```
<script>
$.ajaxSetup({
 timeout:3000,
 success: function(){alert('True!!!');},
 error:function (){
                    alert('false');
                }
});
$.ajax({
 url:'test.php',
});
</script>
```

My 'test.php' is:

```
<?
sleep(8);
$124415;
?>
```

So it`s have parser error, but ajax return "True" immediately, but if the second line have comment, it waiting for 3 sec. and return "false'. Any ideas ?
I have change code test.php:

```
<? 
function shutdown() {
    header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
ob_flush();
}
ob_start();
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
spl_autoload_register('foo');// Fatal Error => Ajax false
//$112123123;//if turn on will be Parse Error => Ajax true
?>
```

So now ajax alert me about fatal error, but Parser Error is not catching. Is anybody know good solution for this problem?

Comment: Is the parser error still a 200, or 500 status coming to the client?

Comment: How can i find out what is error?

Answer (score 6):

Works as designed.

If there's a parser error, the PHP script will fail and terminate immediately. On the ajax end however, this is still a success because PHP sends a `200 OK` header anyway.

(PHP will send a `500` header for fatal errors [only if `error_reporting` and `display_errors` are turned off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075355/php-emitting-500-on-errors-where-is-this-documented).)

If there's no parser error, the script will sleep for 8 seconds, reaching the 3 second timeout, resulting in an Ajax error.

Comment: So my new test.php :<?
error_reporting(0);
echo ini_set('display_errors',0);
sleep(8);

Comment: @Kirill if you're on PHP > 5.2.4, this should throw a 500

Comment: i cant believe that ajax construction will not display error without changing PHP

Comment: @Kirill a PHP error is not a HTTP error, that's the way it is... You could create a custom error handler to send a 500 header but sadly, even that won't work in case of a parse error.

Comment: Ok, I run my script at PHP 5.3.3 with your error off solution, this still not working.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal behaviour: in the first case your php script returns php parse error and ajax gets that,
so your ajax went OK.

Next case your php script runs longer than ajax can wait, so your ajax pops up the error.

Cheers Arman.