# Getting jQuery.ajax to interpret the response as an error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, response

I'm struggling to understand how to get jQuery.ajax to interpret a failed MySQL UPDATE query as an error. Here's my code:

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/ajax/registration.php',
    data:{formData: formData},
    success:function(data){eformDef.forms.registration.success(data);},
    error:function(data){eformDef.forms.registration.success(data);}
});
```

PHP

```
$data = $_POST['formData'];
$firstName = mysql_real_escape_string($data['first name']);
$lastName = mysql_real_escape_string($data['last name']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($data['email address']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($data['password']);


mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$email', '$password')") or die(mysql_error());
```

No matter what--even if I make the mysql_query syntax invalid--the ajax call always interprets the response as a success. I assume that's because the mysql_error() gets sent back as the response, the ajax call reads that as a string, and apparently considers that to be a success. Of course I can deal with this by checking the response string in the $.ajax success function, but this seems a bit illogical. In cases where I can test for a data type using the $.ajax dataType option, this isn't an issue. But with an UPDATE query like the one above, I always get a string as a response.

Since there is a workaround (checking the string in the success function), this isn't a critical issue. But if there is a more correct way of doing this, I'd much prefer that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP will send a  `200 OK` status no matter what<sup>*</sup>, so there is no way to jQuery to detect an error.

You have two possibilities:

- Have the PHP script explicitly output something like "OK" or an JSON encoded array with a status code. Have the jQuery side explicitly look for that "OK" and throw an error if it's not present.
- Have the PHP script throw an error status code if an error occurs, for example:

  ```
    $query = mysql_query(......);

    if (!$query)
     {
       header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
       echo mysql_error(); // Detailed error message in the response body 
       die();
     }
  ```

<sup>*</sup> Except for [this exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075355/php-emitting-500-on-errors-where-is-this-documented).

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Regarding that exception however... It seems to only affect a 500 error. Could I just pass a different error number, such as 404, to gain the same functionality without worrying about the exception you linked to?

Comment: @maxedison if you explicitly throw a 500, that should be fine. You could also throw some other error code, though, there is nothing wrong with that. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: In that case, I guess I don't understand what relevance the "exception" has that you pointed out. I thought you pointed it out to say that throwing a 500 error would always work, except for this kind of exception. No?

Comment: @max no, I meant that as an exception to my first sentence "PHP will send a `200 OK` status no matter what" (hence the star). You can basically throw whatever status code you want, including a 500 (although it's elegant to throw one that fits the problem, like 404 for an invalid record ID. For a database error, a 500 totally makes sense)

Comment: Thanks. Should have noticed which part the exception was referring to :)

Answer (score 2):

The Ajax call will only interpret the response as an error if the HTTP status code indicates that there was an error.  `die` does not set the HTTP status code to 500 (at least the PHP documentation doesn't say so).  If you throw an exception in your code instead of just using `die`, then PHP should return a 500 HTTP status.