# "Internal server error" caused by a PHP error (XAMPP on Mac OS)

Tags: php, xampp

Any error in PHP scripts causes "Internal server error". I used to work for a long time with my current project and it worked fine but I had to upgrade XAMPP package and thus PHP and apache too. Now when there is an error somewhere I can only see "Internal server error" while in the error.log there is a normal error message. I checked php.ini and saw that "display_errors = On" + "log_errors = Off". There no any problems with file permissions nor anything that could override the settings within the project. I'm pretty sure because I worked on this project before the upgrade and everything was fine. Plus if there are no errors in the scripts everything also works.

Please help! Working like this is pain... :(

Comment: "Internal server error" means you need to check your webservers (apache with XAMPP) error.log at first, not PHP's error log. See [What is where? (XAMPP)](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#529). See as well [PHP emitting 500 on errors - where is this documented?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075355/php-emitting-500-on-errors-where-is-this-documented)

Comment: I see this "child pid 21852 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)" in the apache error log but it's not always at the same time as the error from php

Comment: it's not a good sign if the process dies, try installing another version of XAMPP or another similar package. A segmentation fault could be caused by memory problems (hardware) or by memory related bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Make sure that you're editing the right `php.ini`
- Uncomment a line like `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`
- Be sure that there aren't any other `error_reporting` lines uncommented
- Be sure that `display_errors = On` and there are no other lines overwriting the value
- Restart XAMPP