# Codeigniter force_download Internal Server Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, force-download

I’m hosting website on VPS, PHP 5.3 Installed

I’m having problem with force_download method

```
$this->load->helper('download');
$data = file_get_contents('stuff'.$result->file_full_path);
$name = $result->file_name.' - Website.com.'.$result->file_extension;
force_download($name, $data);
```

this is my code

Some files worked perfectly fine but large files ( more than 10mb or 50mb) shows internal server error :(

Please tell me where can i set / change file size limit if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your php `memory_limit` setting.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

You can find similar question with answer here: [500 error when downloading files over 63MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903139/500-error-when-downloading-files-over-63mb)

Try to update your PHP.ini setting and increase your memory limit.

Comment: yes i found this
memory_limit = 1000M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (16MB)
it was 32M i changed it to 1000M for testing but comment is max ammount script may consume is 16mb how can i change that i couldnt find script consume limit in php ini anywhere

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem :)
cant vote you up sorry, reputation only 11